# datastructure behind browsing history

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, array-algorithms

Im writing a QML file browser. Now, I want to implement a *back* and *forward* function. This function is similar to browser back and forward functionality. Example :

I start in "/home/text/folder1" and browse to "/home/text/folder1/src". Now I browse to "/home/text/folder1/src/java". If I press back twice, I should be at "/home/text/folder1", and I cannot press back anymore (the button should be grayed out or in some other way indicate that there are no more "previous" items to be shown).

I was thinking of implementing this via a double-linked list. However, I am having troubles understanding where I should insert new items to the list, and when I should do it.

Take the previous example :
If instead of pressing back twice, I press back only once (I am now in "/home/text/folder1/src"). If I suddenly go to "/home/text/folder2" , what now? How should my double linked list look now?

This is a datastructure question, and not implementation, so code is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your idea using a doubly LinkedList is a good point to start. If you enter a new directory, you add the new item after the current item, discarding the tail of the linked list.

Assume we were in folders 1,2,3 (i.e. we have the list `1->2->[3]`, square brackets indicating current node). Now we go back twice, resulting in `[1]->2->3` if we now go to a new folder 4, we obtain `1->[4]`, so we have discarded the `2->3` part.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a stack, rather than a list. Every forward navigation puts a link on the stack; every time you go back, you remove the item from the stack.

Comment: If i have a stack, then I can't implement the foward functionality? Or?

At the moment, I am thinking of having a currentItem pointer that tells me where in the list I am, and therefore tells me the previous and next item.

My question is primarily :
- When do I insert a new item
- If the item is to be inserted, where do I insert it?

Comment: Ok, I've thought more on this. Maybe having :
- a current node pointer in the double linked list
and then just having a function to add behind the current node. This way, if we have no more "forward" links, a new link gets added as the new tail. If not, the rest of the chain (from current item on) gets discarded and the new tail is just the new link, but you still have the backwards chain